# How can I add a ID to a element only on homepage with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I would like to add jetpack infinity scroll to my webpage.
Unfortunately the div which contain all post, not have `ID` only `class` have him, so I added `ID` with php:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
$homepagepostsid="posts-content";
}else{
  $homepagepostsid="";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="<?php $homepagepostsid ?>" class="loop-container loop-container--wp <?php echo esc_attr($loop_classes); ?>">
</div>
```

As you can see, I tried to reach something like this in some world:
If you're on home page, php add a id to `loop-container loop-container--` div, else the id value is empty.
Unfortunately in somehow this doesn't work, because the infinity scroll trying to load posts to wp-admin area, which loos like this:
.
:
[image]

On the top this text can be found:
"The comments closed"
And the chrome inspector also it confirm that hypothesis , which I mention before.
.
:
[image].
:.
:
The page trying to load the posts to wp admin area.
How can I fix this?

My jetpack infinity scroll code in functions.php:

```
function zilla_infinite_scroll_render() {  
}    
get_template_part( 'loop_item', 'standard' );  
  add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(  
    'container' => 'posts-content',  
    'render'    => 'zilla_infinite_scroll_render',  
    'type'           => 'scroll',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!is_admin` to your condition,

```
$homepagepostsid = is_home() && !is_admin() ? 'posts-content' : '' ;
```

Comment: Dosen't work, it's still trying to load post to wp-admin.

Comment: add the condition  ```is_home() && !is_admin()``` on your jetpack script before embedding it

Comment: Now I dosen't see on home page and wp admin are LOL
And the jetpack said me:
"This theme dosesn't support the infinty scroll"